# "Must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'node'"

Tags: c, data-structures

What is happening here? I'm getting

> Must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'node'

on the `gx` and `hx` lines of

```
typedef struct node {
    char * fx; // function
    node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    node * hx; // right-hand side    
} node;
```

I've also tried

```
typedef struct node {
    char * fx; // function
    node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    node * hx; // right-hand side
};
```

and

```
struct node {
    char * fx; // function
    node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    node * hx; // right-hand side
};
```

and

```
typedef struct  {
    char * fx; // function
    node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    node * hx; // right-hand side
} node;
```

and

```
typedef struct treeNode {
    char * fx; // function
    treeNode  * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    treeNode * hx; // right-hand side
} node;
```

and I get errors for all of those. What is the proper syntax in plain C again?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's look at the first snippet:

```
typedef struct node {
    char * fx; // function
    node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    node * hx; // right-hand side    
} node;
```

`gx` and `hx` occur in the middle of the `struct node`/`node` type definition, before the `typedef` statement is complete.  At this point in the program, `node` is not a valid type name, because the `typedef` isn't over yet (and, unlike C++, writing `struct node { ... };` does not automatically make `node` a type name).  However, `struct node` *is* a valid type name at this point (as long as you only use it for pointer types), so in order to declare `gx` and `hx` properly, you need to write:

```
typedef struct node {
           char * fx; // function
    struct node * gx; // left-hand side
           char * op; // operator
    struct node * hx; // right-hand side    
} node;
```

Answer (score 13):

In c, you can't use the structure name to refer to the `struct`, you need to add `struct` before the name, or you could `typedef` it, like

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node 
 {
    /* Whatever */
    node *link;
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this

```
struct node {
    char        * fx;   // function
    struct node * gx;   // left-hand side
    char        * op;   // operator
    struct node * hx;   // right-hand side
};
typedef struct node node;
```

Comment: Yeah, after seeing iharob's  answer. I'll probably adopt that spacing. Jerk.