# "Unknown type name" in Enum C

Tags: c

It says unknown type name 'week'..
Error showing on 3rd line.

Here is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum week{ sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday };


void lecture_unit(week day)
{
    if (day == friday) printf("COS10008\n");
    if (day == monday) printf("Maths\n");
    if (day == sunday) printf("Holiday\n");
}

int main()
{
    week today;
    today = sunday;
    lecture_unit(today);
    printf("Day %d\n",today);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to either refer to the type as `enum week` (not just `week`), or else use a `typedef` to get the name `week` alone. (And likewise for structs and unions. This is one of the most salient differences between C and C++.)

Comment: The minimum change you have to do is to use `enum` before `week` - then it will run fine

Comment: You probably mean line 6...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'node'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448274/must-use-struct-tag-to-refer-to-type-node)

Answer (score 7):

The correct type name should be `enum week` instead of just `week`

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum week{ sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday };


void lecture_unit(enum week day)
{
    if (day == friday) printf("COS10008\n");
    if (day == monday) printf("Maths\n");
    if (day == sunday) printf("Holiday\n");
}
int main()
{
    enum week today;
    today = sunday;
    lecture_unit(today);
    printf("Day %d\n",today);
    return 0;
}
```

If you prefer to use `week` instead you can use `typedef` to define type `enum week` as `week`

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum week{ sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday };
typedef enum week week;

void lecture_unit(week day)
{
    if (day == friday) printf("COS10008\n");
    if (day == monday) printf("Maths\n");
    if (day == sunday) printf("Holiday\n");
}
int main()
{
    week today;
    today = sunday;
    lecture_unit(today);
    printf("Day %d\n",today);
    return 0;
}
```